# Can`t get JSON data via PHP CURL from URL but browser can

Tags: php, json, curl, browser

Chrom or FF get json data successfully, but if I put some code below then I get something like:

- About to connect() to pager.eudev.bmstu.ru port 80 (#0)
- Trying 195.19.33.153... * Timeout
- connect() timed out!
- Closing connection #0

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$cookie_file = fopen("cookies.txt", "c+");
$err_file = fopen("errors.txt", "c+");
$url = 'http://pager.eudev.bmstu.ru/rasp/o/list/';
$ch = curl_init();

$header=array('GET /rasp/o/list/ HTTP/1.1',
    'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Cache-Control:max-age=0',
    'Connection:keep-alive',
    'Host:pager.eudev.bmstu.ru',
    'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0'
);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $err_file);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$result=curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);



curl_close($ch);


fclose($cookie_file);
fclose($err_file);

exit;
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error your getting from the logs please?

Comment: **errors.txt:**  About to connect() to pager.eudev.bmstu.ru port 80 (#0)
Trying 195.19.33.153... * Timeout
connect() timed out!
Closing connection #0

Comment: **var_dump($result)** gives _bool(false)_

Comment: Try putting in `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);` and see if it makes any difference, I've seen a couple of issues with IPv6 causing issues.

Comment: That`s interesting but not in this case, checked it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url is not responding, neither from a browser nor from you script.

Curl time out is set to two seconds, and it just what's happening, after two seconds of trying to load an unresponsive url, curl stops.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately 195.19.33.153 is in university local net, that`s why it is unresponsive. So one server (195.19.33.153) gives API service for another server, the last one is where this php code executes. Allow_url_fopen is On, CURL support enabled 7.21.7, PHP version is 5.4.38

Comment: Have you tried increasing curl time out or even setting it to zero in order to prevent any timeout ?

Comment: Now adding **curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);** with 0, 1, 10. With zero value script keeps running, other values execute the same "bool(false)"

Comment: I think there`s no bug with timeout because retrieving JSON data is 4-5kB

Comment: I would think that this is a timeout problem. If scripts keeps running with timeout set to 0, then it does not succeed fetching the json.

Comment: ok, I set now __curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);__ but result is the same... I dont understand, why browser gets it easily.. but script doesnt...

Comment: How do you execute this code ? From your computer ? From a server or from the CLI ?

Comment: From a server that is in university local net, 195.19.50.166

Comment: Maybe the server from which you execute your script has no DNS record of the server which provide JSON data, thus explaining why your script fails but not your browser.

Comment: Man... it seems to be the truth..  just a moment for a check

Comment: Hello, vincenth, sorry for late answer. You are man really wise, first trouble was with DNS records. Another trouble was a firewall on the API service server